# How to run only integration tests in cypress

Tags: testing, cypress, e2e-testing

I use cypress for component and for e2e tests. Both tests are in the same folder, .test.e2e.js for e2e tests and .test.ct.ts for component tests. When I run component tests I only want to test the .test.ct.ts files and to test the e2e tests only the .test.e2e.ts files.
It works for component tests, cypress tests only the .test.ct.ts files but when I run the e2e test cypress tests the .test.ct.ts, too and this leads to failed tests.

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "fixturesFolder": "test/cypress/fixtures",
  "integrationFolder": "test/cypress/tests/",
  "pluginsFile": "test/cypress/plugins/index.ts",
  "screenshotsFolder": "test/cypress/screenshots",
  "supportFile": "test/cypress/support/index.ts",
  "videosFolder": "test/cypress/videos",
  "video": false,
  "component": {
    "componentFolder": "test/cypress/tests/",
    "testFiles": ["**/*.test.ct.ts","**/*.test.ct.js"],
    "supportFile": "test/cypress/support/component.ts"
  }
}
```

This is my cypress config file. For component testing I can configure folder and files, I tried this with integration but it didn't work. I'm using cypress 9.7.0

And this is the config I tried

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "fixturesFolder": "test/cypress/fixtures",
  "integration": {
    "integrationFolder": "test/cypress/tests/",
    "testFiles": ["**/*.test.e2e.ts","**/*.test.e2e.js"]
  },
  "pluginsFile": "test/cypress/plugins/index.ts",
  "screenshotsFolder": "test/cypress/screenshots",
  "supportFile": "test/cypress/support/index.ts",
  "videosFolder": "test/cypress/videos",
  "video": false,
  "component": {
    "componentFolder": "test/cypress/tests/",
    "testFiles": ["**/*.test.ct.ts","**/*.test.ct.js"],
    "supportFile": "test/cypress/support/component.ts"
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please show the config when you tried the integration case

Comment: added the config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/legacy-configuration#Examples-1), Cypress configuration defines `e2e` object, not `integration` one.

You can try with `e2e`:

```json
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "fixturesFolder": "test/cypress/fixtures",
  "e2e": {
    "integrationFolder": "test/cypress/tests/",
    "testFiles": ["**/*.test.e2e.ts","**/*.test.e2e.js"]
  },
  "pluginsFile": "test/cypress/plugins/index.ts",
  "screenshotsFolder": "test/cypress/screenshots",
  "supportFile": "test/cypress/support/index.ts",
  "videosFolder": "test/cypress/videos",
  "video": false,
  "component": {
    "componentFolder": "test/cypress/tests/",
    "testFiles": ["**/*.test.ct.ts","**/*.test.ct.js"],
    "supportFile": "test/cypress/support/component.ts"
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI: at StackOverflow, you can accept/vote for an answer to say 'thank you'

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options you can use to make a script that will run only e2e or component tests with `cypress run`. The easiest way would be to use the `--spec` option and pass in the folder path to your e2e tests.
package.json file

```json
[
  "scripts": {
    "e2e": "cypress run --spec 'test/cypress/tests/*.test.e2e.js'"
  }
]
```